# Change aestesics in ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to modify the "New infected", "Mortality" and "TDR level" text characteristics? I want to make it bigger and in bold. How to modify the "Scen1", "Scen2" and "Scen3" text?
I already looked into the R documentation but didn't find an answer in the particular case where barplot are used with "dodge".

Here is the code:

```
myd<- data.frame( var1 = rep(c("Newly infected","Mortality","TDR level"),each=3), 
                     samp = rep(c("Scen1","Scen2","Scen3"),3), 
                  V3 = c(3.5,2,NA,8,2,NA,4,5,NA)/1.5, V2 = c(3.5,2,NA,8,3,NA,4,4.3,NA), V1 = c(1.5,0.2,5,5,3,0.2,4,-5,2) ) 

# rshaping data to long form for ggplot2 
library(reshape2)
meltd<- melt(myd, id.vars=1:2) 
#meltd<- meltd[-which(is.na(meltd$value)),]

ggplot(meltd, aes(x = var1, y = value, fill = variable, label = paste0(round(value * 100, 1), "%"))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(samp ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual("legend",values = c("V3" = "orange", "V2" = "red", "V1" = "blue", "Baseline" = "black")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value + 0.4 * sign(value)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside",
    #axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black"),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))+
  ylab("Relative change (in %)")
```

Here is the plot:

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there, I just added `face`, and `size` arguments:

```
axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", face='bold',size=12),
strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face='bold'))+
 ylab("Relative change (in %)")
```

Or to change the size of the value labels add `size` to `geom_text`:

```
geom_text(aes(y = value + 0.4 * sign(value)), 
 position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), size=6)
```

Full code:

```
ggplot(meltd, aes(x = var1, y = value, fill = variable, label = paste0(round(value * 100, 1), "%"))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(samp ~ ., switch = "y", scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual("legend",values = c("V3" = "orange", "V2" = "red", "V1" = "blue", "Baseline" = "black")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = value + 0.4 * sign(value)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), size=6)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside",
    #axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    # added face and size arguments
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black", face='bold',size=12),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face='bold'))+
  ylab("Relative change (in %)")
```